# Cainozoic vs Cenozoic?

Tags: meaning, synonyms

I came across "Cainozioc" in place of "Cenozoic" for the geological era.  Is this a regional alternative spelling?  I've never seen it before today, where I saw it in Wikipedia, simply redirecting to Cenozioc.  https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Cainozoic

Comment: Interesting. I've never seen that either. Maybe it's an 18th version? I would have figured it came form 'Caenozoic'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be a variant and original term for [Cenozoic](https://www.etymonline.com/word/cenozoic) derived from a Greek kainos meaning “new, fresh, recent, novel".

> The name "Cenozoic" (originally: "Kainozoic") was proposed in 1840 by the British geologist John Phillips (1800–1874). (Wikipedia).

> We observe that Lyell, in his geological works, even the most recent, uses the word Cainozoic instead of Coenozoic or Cenozoic. Why the propounder of the terms Eocene, Miocene, etc., should thus spell the word is incomprehensible. If he is right in it, then to be consistent he ought to say Eocain, Miocain, Pliocain, Post-pliocain; for all have the same root καινός. [American Journal of Sciences and Arts, 1873]

(Etymonline)

Comment: Note that it would likely have been the editor and/or printer, not the author, who decided details like spelling. Also note that any 19th-century English scholar would know Greek, where the spelling `KAIN` was the norm, and would use it wherever it was useful, as when corresponding with other 19th-century English scholars who he knew also understood Greek.

Comment: Yes.  I am surprised that etymology makes such a meal of things.  The intention is obviously to refer to the era when life (Greek zoē - ζωή) was new (Greek kainos - καινός):  so the ’newlifian’ era.  The trouble is the solutions adopted at different times to spelling and pronunciation.  In ancient Greek the ai diphthong was pronounced as in ‘eye’, but has shifted in more modern times towards ‘e’ as in ‘egg’.  Unfortunately, ‘kenos’ means ‘empty’! The ‘oe’ diphthong represents the Latin way of representing Greek ‘oi’.  Greek ‘koinos’ means ‘common’.  The history is a muddle of scribes.

Comment: Thank you all!  I would vote for Kainozioc now, if we had to do it all over again.